# Angular 2 - ngIf Alternative which does not initialize the component evertime the ngIf value changes

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a custom tab implementation, where i show the tab-content with some ngIf directives like this:

```
<tab1 *ngIf="condition === 1"></tab1>
<tab2 *ngIf="condition === 2"></tab2>
```

Tabs have their own forms, some content which should just be initialized once and no more. With my current implementation, everytime i change my condition which then changes the tab, the components tab1 and tab2 are initialized again.

Do we have any other ngIf alternatives (like the old ng-show maybe), which does not initializes the component again and just fade in the new content on UI. Otherwise i have to do it with css (display none).

Comment: maybe use `[hidden]` That doesn't remove tab from DOM.

Comment: You can move the `ngIf` inside the tab component and then it can be initialized only once, but shows no content

Comment: `console.log(condition)`

Comment: @AJT_82 you can write that also as an answer.. i will accept that ;) thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`.

In contrary to `*ngIf`, `hidden` doesn't completely remove content from the DOM, it just... well, hides it ;)

Answer (score 1):

`[hidden]` was suggested, however it's just a native attribute for `display: none` any other CSS that overrides display property will have higher priority. So you should really either do:

`[class.my-hidden-class]="condition"`
or
`[style.display]="condition ? 'none' : null"`
or better to make your own directive with:

```
@Input()
visible = true;

@HostBinding('style.display')
get display(): 'none' | null {
    return this.visible ? null : 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. this will hidden your component without initializing

try this

```
<tab1 [style.display]="condition == 1?'none': 'block'"></tab1>
```

If not work this should work

```
<div [style.display]="condition == 1?'none': 'block'">
<tab1></tab1>
</div>
```